# ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet. % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The problem begins when i fit my `MLPClassifier` model. It shows me this warning:

```
ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (1) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet. % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)
```

But I do not want to solve it, because I'm trying to do a sequential model. What I really want to do is to hide this warning. I've searched for this, but I did not see anything.
How could I hide that warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to attempt to hide these warnings is to `import warnings`, and then:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: What does `filterwarnings` do exactly? By doing this, it will ignore all warnings?

Comment: Yes, it will ignore all warnings, generally.